Almost random number array
Ive used the following formula to write out the numbers 1-4 in random order:
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(BYCOL(SEQUENCE(1,50),LAMBDA(r, RANDBETWEEN(1,4))),1),1,4)
Now I need make sure the number 1 always appear on position 1,2 or 3. How can I achieve this?
I've tried a few different approaches but no luck.

Would you be open to creating a solution using Apps Script?

Here's a possible solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
  s,{1;2;3;4},
  pos,RANDBETWEEN(1,3),
  ini,IF(pos={1;2;3},1,),
  prev,TOCOL(
    {
     IF(pos=1,,SORTN({2;3;4},pos-1,,RANDARRAY(3),));
     ini
    },1),
  {
   prev;
   SORT(FILTER(s,0=COUNTIF(prev,s)),RANDARRAY(4-pos),)
  })) 

The formula is first inserting 1 in a random position (pos) between 1 and 3.
pos ← RANDBETWEEN(1,3)
ini ← IF(pos={1;2;3},1,)

Then it's uniformly picking pos-1 random values from {2;3;4} and prepending them to the initial array.
prev ← TOCOL({
         IF(pos-1=0,,SORTN({2;3;4},pos-1,,RANDARRAY(3),));
         ini
        },1)

And finally, it's appending the remaining values in a random order to the previous array.
s ← {1;2;3;4}
{
 prev;
 SORT(FILTER(s,0=COUNTIF(prev,s)),RANDARRAY(4-pos),)
}


Another naive solution could be to continuously shuffle the numbers 1 to 4 until the restriction is met:
=LET(S,LAMBDA(S,LET(x,SORT({1;2;3;4},RANDARRAY(4),),IF(INDEX(x,4)=1,S(S),x))),S(S))


You May Use Custom Formula
If you are open in using Google Apps Script, this can be done with the following custom formula:
function customShuffle(data) {
  data.sort(()=>Math.random()-0.5);
  if(data[data.length-1] == 1) {
    customShuffle(data)
  }
  return(data)
}

function shuffle1To4() {
  data = [1,2,3,4];
  return(customShuffle(data))
}

The custom function that you should call in Google sheets should be the shuffle1To4() function. The function customShuffle() is there to randomize the 1-4 data and make sure that the number 1 will not be placed on position 4 (or index 3 in the array).
Sample
The result should look like this:

You may use other functions to shuffle1To4() like:
=join(",",shuffle1To4())
which will result in:

I used the function multiple times to check for the output:
Formula application:

Output:

References:

Custom Functions in Google Sheets
Math.random()

